# Collect all value from input html form to object of javascript

Tags: javascript

Normally if I add a new input tag I also have to add in Javascript.

I try to collect all value from input tag,
So how to pass value into an object by loop 
use tag input name to be object key name also.

Try to use for count

```
document.getElementById("form1").elements.length
```

seem it collected the button tag also, how to void it

```
<form name="form1">
 <input type="text" name="value1">
 <input type="text" name="value2">
 <input type="text" name="value3">
 <input type="text" name="value4">

 <input type="button" id="save" onClick="fc1()" value="Save">
</form>


for(i=0;......)
{
    obj.value+'i' =  document.forms["form1"]["value"+ (i+1)].value;
}
```

---

```
Same result as this.


function fc1(){

   this.value1 = document.forms["form1"]["value1"].value;
   this.value2 = document.forms["form1"]["value2"].value;
   this.value3 = document.forms["form1"]["value3"].value;
   this.value4 = document.forms["form1"]["value4"].value;


   const obj = {
      "value1": this.value1,
      "value2": this.value2,
      "value3": this.value3,
      "value4": this.value4
   };

}
```

Comment: Do you mind jquery?

Comment: try giving same 'class' or 'name' attribute to the text fields. try var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example"); which gives you the list of all elements with the class name as "example'. Then you can loop around based on the length of x.

Comment: Use both, I like native javascript more jquery but lastly I accept to use whichever to solve my problem.  Gerardo BLANCO

Answer (score 0):

I usually grab inputs by their ID or class:

`<input type="text" id="value1">`

then grab the value:

`const value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value`

to cut down on code, maybe throw it in an array:

`const valueArray = [value1, value2, value3]`

then you can do something like this:

```
const allValues = {}

valueArray.forEach((value, index) => {
  allValues[`value${index + 1}`] = value
})
```

now when you log `allValues` you should have what you want. Note, I am using some es6.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
var obj = {};
 var form = document.getElementById("form1");
    form.children.forEach(function(elm){
    if(elm.type === 'text'){
        obj[elm.name] = elm.value;
      }
  });
  console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving same 'class' or 'name' attribute to the text fields. 
try `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");`

which gives you the list of all elements with the class name as "example'. Then you can loop around based on the length of x.

**References:**

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll` is made for this.

```
document.querySelectorAll("form[name='form1'] input[type='text']")
```

will return all input fields of type text in `form1` as HTML nodes.

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("form[name='form1'] input[type='text']");

elements.forEach(e => console.log(e.value));
```

...logs the values of the input fields. Don't make things harder on yourself by hard coding classes or ID's, and this will allow you to target the input elements you need without additional checks or without fetching every input on the page.

Example:

```js
const values = {};
document.querySelectorAll("form[name='form1'] input[type='text']").forEach(element => values[element.name] = element.value);

console.log(values);
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input type="text" name="value1" value=1>
  <input type="text" name="value2" value=2>
  <input type="text" name="value3" value=3>
  <input type="text" name="value4" value=4>
  <input type="button" id="save" onclick="fc1()" value="Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution done with jQuery.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```js
//jQuery solution
const obj = {}

$('#save').click(function(e){
  var form = $(this).parent();
  var inputs = form.children().not(':input[type=button]');
  $.each( inputs, function(){
    obj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
  });
  console.log(obj);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>jQuery solution</h2>
<form name="form1">
 <input type="text" name="value1">
 <input type="text" name="value2">
 <input type="text" name="value3">
 <input type="text" name="value4">

 <input type="button" id="save" value="Save">
</form>
```

> JS Solution

```js
//JS Solution
const objs = {}
var button = document.getElementById('savejs'); 
var form = document.getElementById('formjs'); 
var element = {};

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  inputs = form.children;
  for(i=0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].name != ""){

        objs[inputs[i].name] = inputs[i].value;
    }
  }
   console.log(objs);
})
```

```html
<h2>JS solution</h2>
<form name="form1" id='formjs'>
 <input type="text" name="value1">
 <input type="text" name="value2">
 <input type="text" name="value3">
 <input type="text" name="value4">

 <input type="button" id="savejs" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: @TangPhotos Hope this is what you were looking for. Please do not forget to upvote and accepting the answer unless you still need something else. In that case I'll be more than happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var input = document.forms[0].querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
var result = Array.from(input).reduce((r, ele) => {
  r[ele.name] = ele.value;
  return r;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input type="text" name="value1" value=1>
  <input type="text" name="value2" value=2>
  <input type="text" name="value3" value=3>
  <input type="text" name="value4" value=4>
  <input type="button" id="save" onclick="fc1()" value="Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used something like .. I think it will work. :)

```
var myObj = {};
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), i;
for (i in elems) {
    myObj[value + i] = myObj[i].value;
}
```

return from getElementsByTagName is an array of all matching tags. there are some wizard answers in here ha. :)